# How to find number of comparisons and complexity of a given algorithm

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to determine the total number of comparisons (without counting the loops’ stopping conditions) and how the complexity grows with N.

```
1. 
for (int ind = 0; ind < N; ind++)
{
    if (arr[ind] < 0)
        arr[ind] = arr[ind] * 2;
}
2. 
bool there_are_duplicates = false;
for (int ind1 = 0; ind1 < N; ind1++)
{
    for (int ind2 = 0; ind2 < N; ind2++)
        if (ind1 != ind2 && arr[ind1] == arr[ind2])
            there_are_duplicates = true;
}
3. 
for (int ind = 0; ind < N; ind++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int nb = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
        if (ind >= n)
        {
            sum = sum + arr[ind - n];
            nb++;
        }
    }
    arr[ind] = sum / nb;
}
```

**For the first one, complexity is N and number of comparisons is also N or its just equal to one**?

**For the second one, complexity is N^2 and number of comparisons is  2(N^2) or its just equal to two?**

**For the second one, complexity is N and number of comparisons is also 4N or its just equal to one or 4?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's count:

1. You compare for *each* item of the array, so you have `N` comparisons and `O(N)` complexity
2. You have *nested loop*, you compare *every* item (`N` of them) with all the others but theirselves (i.e. with `N - 1` items). You have `N * (N - 1)` comparisons and `O(N^2)` complexity
3. Here, you process *each* item `4` times. So, you have `4 * N` comparisons and `O(N)` complexity

Comment: thank you, what about this one : for (int ind = 0; ind < N; ind++)
{
    if (arr[ind] < 0 && arr[ind] > 20 && arr[ind] % 2 == 0)
        arr[ind] = arr[ind] + arr[ind / 2];
}

Comment: @Jordan: again you test each item: `N` comparisons, `O(N)` complexity

Comment: sorry, don't we consider that in if statement we have 3 comparisons , being called N times, so the number of comparisons is 3N ?

Comment: @Jordan: we have just one `if` with *one condition* (sure it may be complex); if you want to count terms `arr[ind] < 0`, `arr[ind] > 20` etc. you'll have `3 * N` in the worst case, `N` in the best case